# WebApi performance improvement

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I got a `WebApi` as a backend.

**Current Situation:**

- Entity Framework 6 (Code-First)

I read some [articles](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2893714/web-services/improving-web-api-performance.html) about boosting performance and speeding up requests.

As a result I already did the following:

- switched to `Jil` instead of `Newtonsoft.Json`
- implemented `GZip\Deflate`

Another point mentioned was:

> Use faster data access strategies

I don't really get how to do that. 
In another [blog](https://dzone.com/articles/8-ways-improve-aspnet-web-api) here I found this:

[image]

So `EntityFramework` seems not to be the best solution by far.

**My question is how can I get a better/faster data access ?**
Is it really faster using ADO.net ? because I need to parse my objects too when taking this solution.

**Update:**

I just learned about [FOR JSON](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921882.aspx) in SQL Query Syntax. How about that in terms of perforance ?

Comment: But did you mesure what exactly is the bottleneck? Maybe your sql queries are slow, maybe you don't cache anything, many reasons. I mean maybe your are trying to improve perfomance in wrong places.

Comment: While Debugging I just noticed that `DbContext.MyClass.FindAsync(id)` takes just a long time. So I googled - what I found out is that EF may not be the fastest solution.

Comment: @Motivated, if `FindAsync` is slow only when access to the data store is needed, I suggest you take a look at the SQL Server execution plan to make sure the plan is optimal.  Perhaps index/query tuning is needed.

Comment: You need to have really high load to notice the difference from the chart above. You cannot notice that on single select operation (like your FindAsync), so I'm quite sure reason here is not Entity Framework. Most likely generated query is not efficient (missing indexes etc). Same holds for different serialization options.

Comment: Try to get rid of lazy reads in EF, use eager loads when ever you can. That can boost your performance. Also, check queries that are generated by EF and see if those are covered by indexes in database.

Comment: @Evk how can I check if my database uses indexes ?

Comment: Well that's too long story to describe in comments... Start with logging what query exactly EF executes (DbContext.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine or something), then go to your database IDE (sql server management studio for example if you use sql server), run that query there. If slow - show execution plan and look there.